# Angular - Array not sorting after adding data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component called JobList which currently gets a JSON object from a file (will later be a web server) and displays a list of jobs on the page. I want the list to be sorted by a property in each job called Status.Order.

To do this I am using a Pipe which I have setup as in the below code.

**Problem: If I don't use the pipe, the jobs get display in the file order but if I use the pipe then no content is shown at all. Am I doing something wrong in the Pipe code?**

If I add a console.log in the tranform function within the Pipe code then i can see that an empty array is being passed in. I would expect to see a second call when the data is added but get nothing.

```html
export class JoblistComponent implements OnInit {

  private openJobs = new Array();
  private activeJobs = new Array();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const openJobs = this.openJobs;
    const activeJobs = this.openJobs;

    $.getJSON('assets/data/jobs.json', function (json: Array<any>) {

      for (const job of json) {
        if (job.Status.Section === 'Active') {
          activeJobs.push(job);
        } else {
          openJobs.push(job);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

To render the content I am using this HTML.

```html
 <div class="job" *ngFor="let job of openJobs | orderByStatus" [ngStyle]="{ 'border-left-color': job.Group.Colour }">
        <span class="title">12 Example Street, {{job.Location.Name}}</span>
        <span>{{ job.Name }}</span>
        <span>{{ job.Type.Name }}</span>
      </div>
```

```html
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByStatus'
})
export class OrderByStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.Status.Order < b.Status.Order) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.Status.Order > b.Status.Order) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    return array;
  }

}
```

Example Job

```html
{
        "_id": "597b5a700c1d413f20c4d67a",
        "Name": "JOB-20170628-029",
        "Created": "2017-07-28T15:38:24.619Z",
        "Group": {
            "_id": "5919e2f96b1822dc0daf94d5",
            "Name": "Priority 3",
            "Colour": "#1bb934",
            "Order": 3,
            "Class": "priority3"
        },
        "Type": {
            "Name": "Type 2",
            "_id": "597b5a680c1d413f20c4b5fc"
        },
        "Status": {
            "Order": 2,
            "Section": "Active"
        }
        "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed lacus sit amet enim congue molestie. \nAenean pharetra tincidunt ligula a luctus. In vel interdum lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        "Location": {
            "Postcode": "RG31 6PL",
            "Name": "RG31 6PL"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you have some kind of error in your web console? I implemented the same thing in my projects it should be working. Though the only difference I could see is I did not use `new Array()` instead I use the generic one `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access async call in your template. If it load to quick it not load the object at all.

In your html you try:

```
    <span class="title">12 Example Street, {{job.Location.Name}}</span>
    <span>{{ job.Name }}</span>
    <span>{{ job.Type.Name }}</span>
```

Instead it should be `{{job?.Location?.Name}} {{job?.Name}}` in Angular2 or `{{job.Location.Name | async}}` Angular4

Went on a break

**Update**

Try:

If not work put `console.log(a)` and `console.log(b)`

```
if (a.Status.Order < b.Status.Order) {
        return -1;
      } 
if (a.Status.Order > b.Status.Order) {
        return 1;
      } 
        return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the blank issue but the objects are still not being sorted. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[**Docs**](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes): Pipes are by default *pure*...

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Symbol`) or a changed object reference (`Date`, `Array`, `Function`, `Object`).

Here we have no change in object reference, you are just pushing values to the array. You can solve this by marking the pipe as impure:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByStatus'
  pure: false // here
})
```

But I really suggest you would want to reconsider that, performancewise, as the docs continue saying...

> Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change detection cycle. An impure pipe is called often, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.
>
> With that concern in mind, implement an impure pipe with great care. An expensive, long-running pipe could destroy the user experience.

This is the main reason for not having an `orderBy` pipe in Angular, contrary to AngularJS.

I would suggest you implement the sorting and ordering in component after you have received your data :)